# Why swift make difference between a simple string and the result speechRecognizer converted to string?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

If I make the user talk, I transform their channel into a String and display it on a label. Nothing more basic.
I saved `label.text` with a `var test = string ()`
when the user speaks again, swift recognizes perfectly whether the user is saying the same thing as the first time or not. For that, I'm comparing the var test with the new `label.text`

This can work without problems.

My problem is that if I declare a `var test = "Hello"`

Swift marks a difference between the test var and the `label.text` when the user said "Hello"
The worst is that the `label.text` does display "Hello"
I don't understand why Swift makes difference and can't recognize these `two string()`

```
 var test = String()

var isFinal = false
        
        if let result = result {
            // Update the text view with the results.
            let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.textView.text = bestString
            isFinal = result.isFinal
            
            
            
            
            
            if isFinal == false {
                if self.TempsSilence > 0 {
                    if self.TempsSilence >= 5 {
                        isFinal = true
                    } else {
                        self.TempsSilence = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        

        if error != nil || isFinal {
            // Stop recognizing speech if there is a problem.
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            self.recognitionRequest = nil
            self.recognitionTask = nil

            self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
            self.recordButton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: [])
            
            if self.test != "" {
                
                if self.textView.text != self.test {
                        
                        if self.TempsSilence < 5 {
                            self.PrlblResult.text = "⚠️\nVous avez dit:\n\(self.textView.text!)\n\na la place de:\n\(self.test)"
                        } else {
                            self.PrlblResult.text = "voici ce que tu a oublié:\n\(self.test)"
                        }
                    
                } else {
                    self.PrlblResult.text = " ✅ Gagné Super !! ca colle"
                }
            } else {
                
                self.test = self.textView.text
                self.PrlblResult.text = "✅ Sauvegarder"
            }
        }
```

In this example, the test var is empty, and the user's speech "fills it."
The code snippet is truncated. I think I only put what poses a problem without forgetting anything.

if I change `var test = String ()` by `var test = "Hello"` it doesn't work anymore.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is the code you have? You are explaining code but not showing any.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Ideally, you should describe the steps to reproduce the problem starting from "create a new Xcode project".

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I have modified to put a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Since no one was kind enough to help me, I kept looking until I used:

```
let difference = zip (self.test, self.textView.text!). filter {$ 0! = $ 1}
print (difference)

//[("h",""),("e","h"),("l","e"),("l","l"),("o","l")]
```

I noticed that a strange character slipped into the textview which shifted the whole test string to that of the textview.

So I fixed the problem by comparing as follows:

```
 if self.textView.text.dropFirst() != self.test {

      ...

 }
```